# The type was not found

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio writes me some

> The type was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly
>   reference and that all referenced assemblies have been errors in a WPF
>   project from a  user control.

When I press build the message dissapear and everything is ok. After a few seconds this message comes back and disturbs me.

Why does the VS write this and how can I fix it? Thank you in anticipantion

```
   <UserControl x:Class="TandoCare.Desktop.Views.Login"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:TandoCare.Desktop.Infrastructure.Localization"
                 mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Label 
                Width="120px" 
                Content="{loc:Translate UserName}"
                ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:"
                FontSize="16" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                Target="{Binding ElementName=Username}" 
                />
```

Comment: Does the error Description also come with a File, Line, Column and Project? That might be helpful in finding out exactly what is going on.

Comment: In your project, in the References folder, make sure there aren't any assemblies listed there that are showing errors. If there is a yellow icon with an exclamation point on top of the assembly icon, that can mean that Visual studio cannot find the .dll file you are trying to use.

Comment: There is a simple class what is included. Everything is ok, just the vs disturbs me, when I press build it is going to ok again for a 5 minutes

Comment: What is `Translate`? A custom markup extension?

Comment: I'm guessing that you downloaded the TandoCare dll from the web somewhere? If you downloaded it in a .zip file, you might have to "unblock" the zip file before you extract it. Right click the zip file, click properties, and near the bottom, see if there is an "Unblock" button underneath the "Advanced" button.